# How to merge dynamic disk on a new computer?

Tags: windows, dynamic-disk

I have 4 sata disks on a machine. They have been merged together as one drive using dynamic disks on windows. The problem is that the motherboard broke so i just want to pop the drives into my external casing, clone them and then merge them into one drive so i can grab the data again. How do i do this?

Comment: Where is your problem. How to attach the existing spanning disks to a new windows (7?) or how to clone it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

There was no easy way to do this without simply replacing the motherboard, so the system could run as it did before. This somehow worked and I was able to copy everything off. (this time)